# SQL Server : get row data as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am planning to convert following data to a pivoted one by using `pivot`

```
SRNO        DATE        TYPE        USERNAME
--------------------------------------------
1           16/07/2016  OPENING     JOHN
2           13/07/2016  SALES       JOHN
3           12/07/2016  OPENING     JOHN
4           11/07/2016  PURCHASE    ADWARD
5           16/07/2016  OPENING     JOHN
6           13/07/2016  SALES       JOHN
7           12/07/2016  SALES       JOHN
8           12/07/2016  OPENING     JOHN
9           19/07/2016  OPENING     JOHN
10          12/07/2016  PURCHASE    ADWARD
```

I want above table data in following format

```
OPENING_SRNO        OPENING_DATE        OPENING_USERNAME        SALES_SRNO        SALES_DATE        SALES_USERNAME        PURCHASE_SRNO        PURCHASE_DATE        PURCHASE_USERNAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   16/07/2016          JOHN                    2                 13/07/2016        JOHN                  4                    11/07/2016           ADWARD     
3                   12/07/2016          JOHN                    6                 13/07/2016        JOHN                 10                    12/07/2016           ADWARD    
5                   16/07/2016          JOHN                    7                 12/07/2016        JOHN
8                   12/07/2016          JOHN
9                   19/07/2016          JOHN
```

`TYPE` column has dynamic values and I am finding difficulties applying dynamics columns in `pivot in` collection.

**UPDATE**

I tried following but some `NULL` values in `TYPE` column are giving me errors.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @COLS1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @COLS = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(case when TYPE IS NULL then 'empty' else TYPE end) 
                        FROM TEMP
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT(@COLS) 

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select SRNO,DATE, USERNAME
                from TEMP
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(SRNO)
                for TYPE in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

            PRINT @QUERY
execute(@query);
```

Comment: What have you tried? How do you tell, which "OPENING", "SALES" AND "PURCHASE" do belong together? Is it (reading your input table ordered by **SRNO**) strictly/simply "first come, first served"?

Comment: Still: How do you tell, which "OPENING", "SALES" AND "PURCHASE" of your input do belong together - and should end up on the same row of your output?

Comment: @Abecee first come first server or order by srno

Comment: NULL values in TYPE columns are giving me troubles

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, this problem lends itself to `PIVOT`...
This should get you started, though:

```
SELECT
  opening_srno, opening_date, opening_username, sales_srno, sales_date,
  sales_username, purchase_srno, purchase_date, purchase_username
FROM
  (SELECT
    srno OPENING_SRNO
    , d_date OPENING_DATE
    , username OPENING_USERNAME
    , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY srno) rnk
  FROM Data
  WHERE d_type = 'OPENING'
  ) opening
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
      srno SALES_SRNO
      , d_date SALES_DATE
      , username SALES_USERNAME
      , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY srno) rnk
    FROM Data
    WHERE d_type = 'SALES'
    ) sales
  ON opening.rnk = sales.rnk
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
      srno PURCHASE_SRNO
      , d_date PURCHASE_DATE
      , username PURCHASE_USERNAME
      , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY srno) rnk
    FROM Data
    WHERE d_type = 'PURCHASE'
    ) purchase
  ON opening.rnk = purchase.rnk
ORDER BY opening.rnk
;
```

Sorry - no access to a SQL Server instance to verify. (Tested on Oracle.)

<sup>Did not use **TYPE** and **DATE** as column names, as these are SQL reserved words.</sup>

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.